# But by using the -ddump-splices GHC option

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I am learning yesod and would like to know, which code is generated behind, when I am using

```
mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]
```

function.

In the [doc](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/basics), it says:

> We’ll look at this in more detail in the routing chapter. But by using
>   the `-ddump-splices` GHC option, we can get an immediate look at the
>   generated code.

How can I pass `-ddump-splices`  to GHC option?

I start the application with:

```
stack runghc -ddump-splices helloworld.hs
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the [OPTIONS_GHC pragma](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#options-pragma):
simply add

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -ddump-splices #-}
```

at the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to pass options through to GHC when using `stack runghc`.  You can compile your project with `stack build`, which accepts more options.  The full command is `stack build --ghc-options '-ddump-splices'`.

After compiling, you may also want to run your project.  If you followed the [Yesod quickstart](https://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart), I think `stack exec -- yesod devel` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this today when working through the Yesod Book. The following seems to work well. Any option passed before `--` is passed to stack and options after `--` are passed directly to GHC

```
stack runghc -- -ddump-splices helloworld.hs
```